# How can I assign a keyboard shortcut to a specific application in Openbox?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox

I use the web browser [Uzbl](http://uzbl.org) and the window manager Openbox, and I wondered if I could configure openbox to add a keyboard shortcut to minimize / maximize Uzbl's window ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> is the default shortcut for maximize/unmaximize in most window managers.  Does that work?

Or maybe it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> as suggested in the [Actions Documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aActions#MaximizeFull).

If not, you can add a binding using the information in the [Openbox Bindings Documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aBindings), but it sounds like you can only set shortcuts for all windows, not just for one program.

In brief, you find your `rc.xml` file, then add something like this in the middle of it:

```
<keybind key="A-F6">
  <action name="MaximizeFull"/>
</keybind>
```

Unless you meant **unminimize** / **restore** rather than maximize, i.e. a binding that works even when the window isn't focussed.

In that case, I'd suggest using `xbindkeys` and `wmctrl`.  You'd have to write a script that runs `wmctrl` to find the `uzbl` window using `wmctrl -l`, then run either `wmctrl -a <win>` or `wmctrl -R <win>`, then add an entry in `.xbindkeysrc` to run that script whenever a specific keyboard combination was pressed.

Answer (score 4):

> In that case, I'd suggest using
>   xbindkeys and wmctrl.

I've googled for "wmctrl examples" and I found http://spiralofhope.com/wmctrl-examples.html#s12

So I added the following lines to my openbox configuration:

```
<keybind key="C-F1">
  <action name="Execute">
    <execute>wmctrl -x uzbl-tabbed -a uzbl-tabbed.Uzbl-tabbed -b toggle,hidden</execute>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

It works exactly as I wanted!