# Keyboard-bound applications in Openbox

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox, lxde, focus

Following the template of [another stack user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6383/how-can-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-specific-application-in-openbox) I've bound a keyboard shortcut to toggle an application between hidden and fullscreen. The only problem is, **no matter what application I apply it to**, I have to manually focus it after it pops up. Here's the relevant portions of my config:

```
<keybind key="F10">
  <action name="Execute">
    <execute>wmctrl -x gvim -a gvim.alwayson -b toggle,fullscreen,hidden</execute>
  </action>
</keybind>
...
<application name="gvim"
             class="alwayson">
  <focus>yes</focus>
  <maximized>true</maximized>
  <decor>no</decor>
  <skip_taskbar>yes</skip_taskbar>
</application>
```

I've played with all the relevant-seeming [openbox actions](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions) and [wmctrl flags](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl).

### Update

A wmctrl solution remains elusive. However xdotool and [a bashscript](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=550380#p550380) can toggle any application in a single command, which can then be bound to a key.